# during her slot

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read ["Losers of the Week"](http://www.gigwise.com/photos/73594/6/losers-of-the-week-madonna-doherty-subo-and-more#gallery) on the Internet, and came across the phrase 'during her slot as guest judge'. I understand what the guest judge means in the context of the TV show 'X Factor'. I have a hard time understanding 'during her slot'. Does it mean something like 'her turn to vote for a performer'?

> Former Spice Girl MEL B was booed by an X Factor audience during her slot as guest judge at the talent show auditions. "I wanted to fall asleep", she said to the elderly entrant, which provoked an angry response from the audience.

Answer (score 1):

I assume they have a different guest judge every show — otherwise *guest* would be a strange description.

A (time) slot is an allocated period of time in which one can do something.

So

> her slot as guest judge

Means “during her allocated period as a guest judge”.

So it's not just about one specific moment she had to judge one candidate, but it's about the whole episode during which she acted as a judge on the program.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer confirmed my assumption about the time slot.