# "I do my classes in/on SLOT #2"? What to put before 'slot'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

**Context**

In my country, there are specialised "coaching centres" for IGCSE and IAL students. The same classes are usually held on multiple different timings. This we call "slot".

> For instance:
>
> My English Language class has two slots. Slot 1 is 3:30—5:00 PM. And slot 2 is 6:30—8:00 PM.

It's much like "shift". Only that is used to refer to work timings, not class timings.

Check out: [during her slot](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53170).

---

This is what I'm writing:

> Can we sit the monthly tests ***in*** whichever slot we wish to? Or it has to be the one I do my classes ***on***?

What preposition to put before "slot" in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Slot* is likely to be understood in this context, but a few other terms you might hear in specific academic contexts:

1. "Period" - in a high school, for example, everyone runs by the same rigid schedule, so you might ask your friend: "**What class do you have *next period*?**"
2. "Section" - the same class taught at two different times (typically at a university) are usually referred to as different "sections" of the class. "**You've got Jones for English too? Which section?**"
3. "Hour" - Even if classes don't start exactly at the top of the hour, you might still refer to different class slots throughout the day as "hours": "**What hour tomorrow is your paper due?**"

For your example sentence, you would use *in*. I might word it as:

> Can we take the monthly tests in whichever slot we wish to? Or does it have to be the same hour I normally attend class?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The idea of using "hour" instead is much more convenient.

Comment: "Sit a test" is standard in British English. And in case you didn't notice, IGCSE and IAL are exams organised by British boards like Edexcel and Cambridge.

Answer (score 1):

Just for background: It's common in US English to talk about "time slots", so this terminology would be unlikely to be confusing to native speakers. However, when talking about time slots for classes in school, we usually refer to them as "periods".

Anyway, the short answer to your question is: "in", or to give no preposition at all. "My history class is in slot 1." "My history class is slot 1."

In US English we say you "take" a test, not "sit" a test.

So a native US English speaker would say, "Can we take the monthly tests in whichever slot we wish to? Or does it have to be the one I take my classes in?" Or more likely, "... Or does it have to be the same slot as my regular class time?"

Comment: "Sit a test" *is* standard in British English. And in case you didn't notice, IGCSE and IAL are exams organised by British boards like Edexcel and Cambridge.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine I was going to say something about "maybe 'sit a test' is the idiom in some other English dialect" but then dropped that as wordy and speculative. Thanks for the addition. I had no idea what IGCSE and IAL are, so that was no help.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/In-English-grammar-does-a-person-sit-an-exam-or-sit-for-an-exam

Comment: Haven't heard of  "O-levels" and "A-levels"?

Comment: And it's not school. There's no definite schedule everyone runs by.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine "O-levels and A-levels" No, those terms mean nothing to me. Are they levels of British tests? I'm an American. Do you know the difference between a PSAT and a SAT?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Hmm, if there are "classes" and "students", this sounds to me pretty much like the definition of a "school". If there are time slots in which these classes are taught and tests are given, this sounds like the definition of a "schedule". I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to make.

Comment: I think BradC understood the context best. Read his answer more carefully. And naturally it would be hard for you to understand, because the whole concept of a "coaching centre" for grade school students is foreign to Americans.

Comment: It's more like "after school tuition" or a "cram school".

Comment: **tuition** means something very different in BrE and AmE.  In AmE, tuition is the cost of the schooling, what the school charges students to attend.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine I still don't see what point you're trying to make. So it's not a "regular" school, it's a place where students go for special classes. Maybe British usage is different, but in America, if, for example, an adult takes a class in the evening so it doesn't interfere with working a regular job, we refer to that as "night school". And whether a set of time slots occurs during normal working hours or in the evening or on weekends, we still call that a "schedule". In any case, I don't see what any of this has to do with what preposition should be used with "slot".

Answer (score 1):

The word **slot** in this context is new to me.

Because a *slot* usually refers to a small space into which a tongue fits to make a joint (as in a mortise and tenon joint), the inclination is to say **in** a slot.

But because your *slot* really refers to a shift and we speak about **on** a shift or **during** a shift, it's hard to know which preposition best suits your purpose.

I would go with **in whichever slot**.